# Flex - children fixed position and 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A menu that is fixed with 100 height (stretched over the height).
If het content in the menu is growing outside the div a scrollbar must be shown within the menu. It may not grow more than the 100 height.

the page-content may grow to any height (min-height also stretched over the height of the parent). If the content size is growing the default scrollbar must be shown (on the right)

HTML:

```
<div class="module">
      <nav class="vertical-menu">
        <header>
          <h5>Menu</h5>
        </header>
        <div class="menu-links">
          menu link<br/>
          menu link<br/>
          menu link<br/>
          menu link<br/>
          menu link<br/>
          menu link<br/> 
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="page-content">
        Some content<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
        another line<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .module {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    .vertical-menu {
      margin: 10px 0;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: coral;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    .vertical-menu h5 {
      font-size: 23px;
      padding: 10px 22px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    .page-content {
      margin: 10px;
      background: tomato;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/Babulaas/pen/ZoPvmO

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBEpOR#anon-login

So, you want the sidebar to stay always visible, while scrolling the page.

You should wrap content of `.vertical-menu` to helper container `.vertical-menu-body` and:

- position it as `fixed`;
- give it the same width as `.vertical-menu`
- enable scrolling with `overflow-y: scroll`;
- constraint it's height with `max-height: 100vh`.

Full code.

css:

```
.module {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.vertical-menu {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-menu-body {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="module">
  <nav class="vertical-menu">
    <div class="vertical-menu-body">
      <header>
        <h5>Menu</h5>
      </header>
      <div class="menu-links">
        menu link<br/>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="page-content">
    Some content<br/>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```